# What is the longnest blockchain fork that has been orphaned to date?

Tags: blockchain-fork, history, stale-block

On [this](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=longest+blockchain+fork+that+has+been+site:bitcoin.stackexchange.com&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwib29-WocfdAhUGhpAKHfIzCG4QrQIoBDAAegQICRAM&biw=1680&bih=971) thread, the user asked what is the longest unintentional fork that Bitcoin had suffered. From the answers present, Bitcoin never had a >4 block fork until 2012.

It has been 6 years though, and I wonder if there is a more up-to-date statistics on that question, and if any study has been done so far.

Answer (score 1):

11/12 March 2013 Chain Fork at block height 225,430.It's 31 blocks long.

Comment: Wow, was that a brute PoW fork? Or was that a bug / protocol patch or similar?

Comment: It was an issue with version of bitcoin client.Miner mined with the version 0.8.0 which wasn't compatible with version 0.7